# Arms repositioned after exporting if animation is not current one?

Tags: modeling

If I'm on another animation when I export as auto desk, the arms of my animation I'm not on get messed up position wise? I hit f and everything. I don't know if I should press the 3 but maybe? help!!!

Comment: Hasnt anyone had this problem? :(

Comment: Without exact workflow  and an image before and after the problem occurs it is unlikely that one can help you. _I hit f and everything_ - I couldn't predict what happens when I would do this.